# Interactive BSpline fitting in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, draggable, curve-fitting, bspline

Using the following function, one can fit a cubic spline on input points P:

```
def plotCurve(P):
  pts = np.vstack([P, P[0]])
  x, y = pts.T
  i = np.arange(len(pts))

  interp_i = np.linspace(0, i.max(), 100000 * i.max())

  xi = interp1d(i, x, kind='cubic')(interp_i)  
  yi = interp1d(i, y, kind='cubic')(interp_i)

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  fig,ax=plt.subplots()
  ax.plot(xi, yi)
  ax.plot(x, y, 'ko')
  #plt.show()
  return xi,yi
```

The input points P can be of the following form:

```
P=[(921,1181),(951,1230),(993,1243),(1035,1230),
    (1065,1181),(1045,1130),(993,1130),(945,1130)]
```

Now, I wish to make these points of P draggable, such that as and when we change the position of any point, the spline gets refitted on the new points.

Using this as a reference: https://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/event_handling/poly_editor.html (event handling in matplotlib), I have the following code:

```
"""
This is an example to show how to build cross-GUI applications using
matplotlib event handling to interact with objects on the canvas

"""
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.artist import Artist
from matplotlib.mlab import dist_point_to_segment

class PolygonInteractor:
    """
    An polygon editor.
Key-bindings

  't' toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
      you can move them, delete them

  'd' delete the vertex under point

  'i' insert a vertex at point.  You must be within epsilon of the
      line connecting two existing vertices

"""
showverts = True
epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

def __init__(self, ax, poly):
    if poly.figure is None:
        raise RuntimeError('You must first add the polygon to a figure or canvas before defining the interactor')
    self.ax = ax
    canvas = poly.figure.canvas
    self.poly = poly

    x, y = zip(*self.poly.xy)
    self.line = Line2D(x, y, marker='o', markerfacecolor='r', animated=True)
    self.ax.add_line(self.line)
    #self._update_line(poly)

    cid = self.poly.add_callback(self.poly_changed)
    self._ind = None # the active vert

    canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.draw_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)
    self.canvas = canvas


def draw_callback(self, event):
    self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
    self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)

def poly_changed(self, poly):
    'this method is called whenever the polygon object is called'
    # only copy the artist props to the line (except visibility)
    vis = self.line.get_visible()
    Artist.update_from(self.line, poly)
    self.line.set_visible(vis)  # don't use the poly visibility state


def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
    'get the index of the vertex under point if within epsilon tolerance'

    # display coords
    xy = np.asarray(self.poly.xy)
    xyt = self.poly.get_transform().transform(xy)
    xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
    d = np.sqrt((xt-event.x)**2 + (yt-event.y)**2)
    indseq = np.nonzero(np.equal(d, np.amin(d)))[0]
    ind = indseq[0]

    if d[ind]>=self.epsilon:
        ind = None

    return ind

def button_press_callback(self, event):
    'whenever a mouse button is pressed'
    if not self.showverts: return
    if event.inaxes==None: return
    if event.button != 1: return
    self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

def button_release_callback(self, event):
    'whenever a mouse button is released'
    if not self.showverts: return
    if event.button != 1: return
    self._ind = None

def key_press_callback(self, event):
    'whenever a key is pressed'
    if not event.inaxes: return
    if event.key=='t':
        self.showverts = not self.showverts
        self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
        if not self.showverts: self._ind = None
    elif event.key=='d':
        ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
        if ind is not None:
            self.poly.xy = [tup for i,tup in enumerate(self.poly.xy) if i!=ind]
            self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
    elif event.key=='i':
        xys = self.poly.get_transform().transform(self.poly.xy)
        p = event.x, event.y # display coords
        for i in range(len(xys)-1):
            s0 = xys[i]
            s1 = xys[i+1]
            d = dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1)
            if d<=self.epsilon:
                self.poly.xy = np.array(
                    list(self.poly.xy[:i]) +
                    [(event.xdata, event.ydata)] +
                    list(self.poly.xy[i:]))
                self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
                break


    self.canvas.draw()

def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
    'on mouse movement'
    if not self.showverts: return
    if self._ind is None: return
    if event.inaxes is None: return
    if event.button != 1: return
    x,y = event.xdata, event.ydata

    self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x,y
    self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))

    self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
    self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

#theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
#r = 1.5

#xs = r*np.cos(theta)
#ys = r*np.sin(theta)
xs = (921, 951, 993, 1035, 1065, 1045, 993, 945)
ys = (1181, 1230, 1243, 1230, 1181, 1130, 1130, 1130)

poly = Polygon(list(zip(xs, ys)), animated=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(poly)
p = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly)

#ax.add_line(p.line)
ax.set_title('Click and drag a point to move it')
#ax.set_xlim((-2,2))
#ax.set_ylim((-2,2))

ax.set_xlim((800, 1300))
ax.set_ylim((1000, 1300))

plt.show()
```

Now, what I wish to do is to replace the polygon fitting with my spline fitting function. As I am new to this I am not able to figure out how to do it. 
Is there any way to keep all the same functionalities, but only to fit the spline instead of polygon through the given points, making it interactive and refitting the spline as per point movement?

My spline would look somewhat like this :

[image]

How should I go about doing it?

Or, if there is any other suitable method to achieve the same, kindly recommend.

Suggestions are also welcome using MATLAB.

Comment: That is sure possible. Since you have your fitting function and the interactive feature available, what exact problem do you face when combining them?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest since I am not familiar with these functions I am not able to replace the part where the poly.figure.canvas is created with my own function. Can you help me combine the two?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest apparently some of the functions being used are only for poly.figure? can't I extend the _update_line etc for my cubic spline??

Comment: `dist_point_to_segment` was removed from mlab but the source of that and the dist function can be copied in from here: https://matplotlib.org/3.0.0/_modules/matplotlib/mlab.html#dist_point_to_segment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you need to add your function to the `PolygonInteractor`. Don't let it draw anything itself though. 
Then add a new line to the class, `self.line2` which will be the line to update.

Finally, let the class draw your new line as well. And update it with the result from your interpolation function.

For convenience you may turn the Polygon (`self.poly`) invisible, also removing the line from the `self.line` and only showing the points may make sense.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from  scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.artist import Artist
from matplotlib.mlab import dist_point_to_segment


class PolygonInteractor(object):

    """
    A polygon editor.
    https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html

    Key-bindings

      't' toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
          you can move them, delete them

      'd' delete the vertex under point

      'i' insert a vertex at point.  You must be within epsilon of the
          line connecting two existing vertices

    """

    showverts = True
    epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

    def __init__(self, ax, poly, visible=False):
        if poly.figure is None:
            raise RuntimeError('You must first add the polygon to a figure '
                               'or canvas before defining the interactor')
        self.ax = ax
        canvas = poly.figure.canvas
        self.poly = poly
        self.poly.set_visible(visible)

        x, y = zip(*self.poly.xy)
        self.line = Line2D(x, y, ls="",
                           marker='o', markerfacecolor='r',
                           animated=True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)

        self.cid = self.poly.add_callback(self.poly_changed)
        self._ind = None  # the active vert

        canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.draw_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)
        self.canvas = canvas

        x,y = self.interpolate()
        self.line2 = Line2D(x, y, animated=True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line2)

    def interpolate(self):
        x, y = self.poly.xy[:].T
        i = np.arange(len(x))

        interp_i = np.linspace(0, i.max(), 100 * i.max())

        xi = interp1d(i, x, kind='cubic')(interp_i)  
        yi = interp1d(i, y, kind='cubic')(interp_i)

        return xi,yi

    def draw_callback(self, event):
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line2)
        # do not need to blit here, this will fire before the screen is
        # updated

    def poly_changed(self, poly):
        'this method is called whenever the polygon object is called'
        # only copy the artist props to the line (except visibility)
        vis = self.line.get_visible()
        Artist.update_from(self.line, poly)
        self.line.set_visible(vis)  # don't use the poly visibility state


    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
        'get the index of the vertex under point if within epsilon tolerance'

        # display coords
        xy = np.asarray(self.poly.xy)
        xyt = self.poly.get_transform().transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
        d = np.hypot(xt - event.x, yt - event.y)
        indseq, = np.nonzero(d == d.min())
        ind = indseq[0]

        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def button_press_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a mouse button is pressed'
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def button_release_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a mouse button is released'
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None

    def key_press_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a key is pressed'
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        if event.key == 't':
            self.showverts = not self.showverts
            self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
            if not self.showverts:
                self._ind = None
        elif event.key == 'd':
            ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
            if ind is not None:
                self.poly.xy = np.delete(self.poly.xy,
                                         ind, axis=0)
                self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
        elif event.key == 'i':
            xys = self.poly.get_transform().transform(self.poly.xy)
            p = event.x, event.y  # display coords
            for i in range(len(xys) - 1):
                s0 = xys[i]
                s1 = xys[i + 1]
                d = dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1)
                if d <= self.epsilon:
                    self.poly.xy = np.insert(
                        self.poly.xy, i+1,
                        [event.xdata, event.ydata],
                        axis=0)
                    self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
                    break
        if self.line.stale:
            self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
        'on mouse movement'
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if self._ind is None:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

        self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x, y
        if self._ind == 0:
            self.poly.xy[-1] = x, y
        elif self._ind == len(self.poly.xy) - 1:
            self.poly.xy[0] = x, y
        self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))

        x,y = self.interpolate()
        self.line2.set_data(x,y)

        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line2)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

    #theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
    #r = 1.5

    #xs = r*np.cos(theta)
    #ys = r*np.sin(theta)
    xs = (921, 951, 993, 1035, 1065, 1045, 993, 945)
    ys = (1181, 1230, 1243, 1230, 1181, 1130, 1130, 1130)

    poly = Polygon(list(zip(xs, ys)), animated=True)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_patch(poly)
    p = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly, visible=False)

    ax.set_title('Click and drag a point to move it')

    ax.set_xlim((800, 1300))
    ax.set_ylim((1000, 1300))

    plt.show()
```

Note that the curve created here is not truely cyclic. It has a start point where the curve is not really smooth. This can be circumvented by using a truely cyclic set of bezier curves as shown in [Create random shape/contour using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731785/create-random-shape-contour-using-matplotlib).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I see now how to go about it. If I also want to dynamically compute the length of the curve(check edit for the function) and display it along with the figure as and when we move the points, how to go about it? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: I suggest you do not modify the question after it has been answered. The question how to change some text in the axes has surely already an answer somewhere else.

Comment: Hello I am searching a gui curve to normalice values like photoshop, 3d program... any help Reggards.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537721/gui-2d-curves-to-normalice-values-change-values   you example is lovelly

Comment: Some import are now deprecated, the `PolygonInteractor` should be modified according to this: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html?highlight=poly%20editor

Answer (score 3):

Un update and some improvements to the answer of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. The `dist_point_to_segment`is no more supported in `matplotlib` and the class should be modified accordingly to the new [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html?highlight=poly%20editor).

Apart from this I think that could be useful to have the point insertion functionality also for the spline curve, that actually is missing. Since a point control for the curve can be added only to the straight line I made this visible with a dashed style. The visibility of this line can be toggle with the 't' button. The interpolate function is now defined more generally outside the class and the visible property of the polygon can be set directly when declared instead of modifying it inside the class. In this way the class results more clean and with less modifications. Here's my result and my code:

[image: poly-result]

```
"""
===========
Poly Editor
===========

This is an example to show how to build cross-GUI applications using
Matplotlib event handling to interact with objects on the canvas.
"""
import numpy as np
from  scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.artist import Artist


def dist(x, y):
    """
    Return the distance between two points.
    """
    d = x - y
    return np.sqrt(np.dot(d, d))


def dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1):
    """
    Get the distance of a point to a segment.
      *p*, *s0*, *s1* are *xy* sequences
    This algorithm from
    http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html
    """
    v = s1 - s0
    w = p - s0
    c1 = np.dot(w, v)
    if c1 <= 0:
        return dist(p, s0)
    c2 = np.dot(v, v)
    if c2 <= c1:
        return dist(p, s1)
    b = c1 / c2
    pb = s0 + b * v
    return dist(p, pb)


def interpolate(x, y):
    x, y = x, y##self.poly.xy[:].T
    i = np.arange(len(x))

    interp_i = np.linspace(0, i.max(), 100 * i.max())

    xi = interp1d(i, x, kind='cubic')(interp_i)
    yi = interp1d(i, y, kind='cubic')(interp_i)

    return xi,yi


class PolygonInteractor:
    """
    A polygon editor.

    Key-bindings

      't' toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
          you can move them, delete them

      'd' delete the vertex under point

      'i' insert a vertex at point.  You must be within epsilon of the
          line connecting two existing vertices

    """

    showverts = True
    epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

    def __init__(self, ax, poly):
        if poly.figure is None:
            raise RuntimeError('You must first add the polygon to a figure '
                               'or canvas before defining the interactor')
        self.ax = ax
        canvas = poly.figure.canvas
        self.poly = poly

        x, y = zip(*self.poly.xy)
        self.line = Line2D(x, y, ls = '--',
                           marker='o', markerfacecolor='r',
                           animated=True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)

        xs, ys = self.poly.xy[:].T
        xs, ys = interpolate(xs, ys)
        self.spline = Line2D(xs, ys, animated = True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.spline)

        self.cid = self.poly.add_callback(self.poly_changed)
        self._ind = None  # the active vert

        canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.on_draw)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press)
        canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key_press)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_button_release)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_mouse_move)
        self.canvas = canvas

    def on_draw(self, event):
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.spline)
        # do not need to blit here, this will fire before the screen is
        # updated

    def poly_changed(self, poly):
        """This method is called whenever the pathpatch object is called."""
        # only copy the artist props to the line (except visibility)
        vis = self.line.get_visible()
        Artist.update_from(self.line, poly)
        self.line.set_visible(vis)  # don't use the poly visibility state

    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
        """
        Return the index of the point closest to the event position or *None*
        if no point is within ``self.epsilon`` to the event position.
        """
        # display coords
        xy = np.asarray(self.poly.xy)
        xyt = self.poly.get_transform().transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
        d = np.hypot(xt - event.x, yt - event.y)
        indseq, = np.nonzero(d == d.min())
        ind = indseq[0]

        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse button presses."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse button releases."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        """Callback for key presses."""
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        if event.key == 't':
            self.showverts = not self.showverts
            self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
            if not self.showverts:
                self._ind = None
        elif event.key == 'd':
            ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
            if ind is not None:
                self.poly.xy = np.delete(self.poly.xy,
                                         ind, axis=0)
                self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
        elif event.key == 'i':
            xys = self.poly.get_transform().transform(self.poly.xy)
            p = event.x, event.y  # display coords
            for i in range(len(xys) - 1):
                s0 = xys[i]
                s1 = xys[i + 1]
                d = dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1)
                if d <= self.epsilon:
                    self.poly.xy = np.insert(
                        self.poly.xy, i+1,
                        [event.xdata, event.ydata],
                        axis=0)
                    self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
                    xs, ys = self.poly.xy[:].T
                    xs, ys = interpolate(xs, ys)
                    self.spline.set_data(xs, ys)
                    break
        if self.line.stale:
            self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse movements."""
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if self._ind is None:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

        self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x, y
        if self._ind == 0:
            self.poly.xy[-1] = x, y
        elif self._ind == len(self.poly.xy) - 1:
            self.poly.xy[0] = x, y

        self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))

        xs, ys = self.poly.xy[:].T
        xs, ys = interpolate(xs, ys)
        self.spline.set_data(xs, ys)

        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.spline)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

    theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
    r = 1.5

    #xs = r * np.cos(theta)
    #ys = r * np.sin(theta)
    xc = (921, 951, 993, 1035, 1065, 1045, 993, 945)
    yc = (1181, 1230, 1243, 1230, 1181, 1130, 1130, 1130)

    poly = Polygon(np.column_stack([xc, yc]), animated=True, visible = False)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_patch(poly)
    p = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly)

    ax.set_title('Click and drag a point to move it')
    ax.set_xlim((800, 1300))
    ax.set_ylim((1000, 1300))
    plt.show()
```

Anyway I think that a better way to achieve this result in fewer lines of code is using a path editor like that shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/path_editor.html): it avoids the use of a polygon and the code results much easier. Here's my code to obtain the same result shown above:

```
"""
===========
Path Editor
===========

Sharing events across GUIs.

This example demonstrates a cross-GUI application using Matplotlib event
handling to interact with and modify objects on the canvas.
"""

import numpy as np
from  scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def interpolate(x, y):
    x, y = x, y
    i = np.arange(len(x))

    interp_i = np.linspace(0, i.max(), 100 * i.max())

    xi = interp1d(i, x, kind='cubic')(interp_i)
    yi = interp1d(i, y, kind='cubic')(interp_i)

    return xi,yi

def dist(x, y):
    """
    Return the distance between two points.
    """
    d = x - y
    return np.sqrt(np.dot(d, d))

def dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1):
    """
    Get the distance of a point to a segment.
      *p*, *s0*, *s1* are *xy* sequences
    This algorithm from
    http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html
    """
    v = s1 - s0
    w = p - s0
    c1 = np.dot(w, v)
    if c1 <= 0:
        return dist(p, s0)
    c2 = np.dot(v, v)
    if c2 <= c1:
        return dist(p, s1)
    b = c1 / c2
    pb = s0 + b * v
    return dist(p, pb)



class PathInteractor:
    """
    An path editor.

    Press 't' to toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
    they can be dragged with the mouse.
    """

    showverts = True
    epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

    def __init__(self, spline, verts):

        self.ax = spline.axes###pathpatch.axes
        canvas = self.ax.figure.canvas
        self.verts = verts
        self.spline = spline
        self.spline.set_animated(True)

        x, y = zip(*self.verts)

        self.line, = ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', ls = '--',
                             markerfacecolor='r', animated=True)

        self._ind = None  # the active vertex

        canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.on_draw)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press)
        canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key_press)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_button_release)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_mouse_move)
        self.canvas = canvas

    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
        """
        Return the index of the point closest to the event position or *None*
        if no point is within ``self.epsilon`` to the event position.
        """
        # display coords
        #xy = verts #np.asarray(self.pathpatch.get_path().vertices)
        xyt = self.spline.get_transform().transform(self.verts)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
        d = np.sqrt((xt - event.x)**2 + (yt - event.y)**2)
        ind = d.argmin()

        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def on_draw(self, event):
        """Callback for draws."""
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.spline)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse button presses."""
        if (event.inaxes is None
                or event.button != MouseButton.LEFT
                or not self.showverts):
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse button releases."""
        if (event.button != MouseButton.LEFT
                or not self.showverts):
            return
        self._ind = None

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        """Callback for key presses."""
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        if event.key == 't':
            self.showverts = not self.showverts
            self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
            if not self.showverts:
                self._ind = None
        elif event.key == 'i':
            xys = self.spline.get_transform().transform(verts)
            p = event.x, event.y
            for i in range(len(xys) - 1):
                s0 = xys[i]
                s1 = xys[i + 1]
                d = dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1)
                if d <= self.epsilon:
                    self.verts.insert(i+1, (event.xdata, event.ydata))
                    self.line.set_data(zip(*self.verts))
                    x, y = interpolate(*zip(*self.verts))
                    self.spline.set_data(x, y)

        self.canvas.draw()

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        """Callback for mouse movements."""
        if (self._ind is None
                or event.inaxes is None
                or event.button != MouseButton.LEFT
                or not self.showverts):
            return

        #vertices = verts

        self.verts[self._ind] = event.xdata, event.ydata
        self.line.set_data(zip(*self.verts))
        x, y = interpolate(*zip(*self.verts))
        self.spline.set_data(x, y)

        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.spline)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)



fig, ax = plt.subplots()

verts = [
    (921, 1181),
    (951, 1230),
    (993, 1243),
    (1035, 1230),
    (1065, 1181),
    (1045, 1130),
    (993, 1130),
    (945, 1130),
    (921, 1181)
]

x, y = interpolate(*zip(*verts))
spline = Line2D(x,y)
ax.add_line(spline)

interactor = PathInteractor(spline, verts)
ax.set_title('drag vertices to update path')
ax.set_xlim(800, 1300)
ax.set_ylim(1000, 1300)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you for the code! I wonder if it is also possible to activate the handles of the control points so I can better control them ?

Comment: I don't know if I get your question right, but there are no other points besides those shown since the curve fitted is a polynomial spline interpolation and not segments of a Bezier curve (I think that you're referring to this case) where there are other control points determining the curvature.

Comment: Yes, my target is the write a piece of code to fit a bezier curve segments to my already existing data. Afterwards I would like to extract the numerical data from the bezier curve itself. Which would give me a smooth approximation of my data!

Comment: Ok, so I think that you should look for other questions relating to Bezier curves, or otherwise open a new one asking for help. Your concern is not related to this answer.