# How to control point movement directions for mouse-draggable points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, draggable, curve-fitting, bspline

Using the following as reference : [Interactive BSpline Fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570341/interactive-bspline-fitting-in-python/49576600?noredirect=1#comment86168874_49576600) I have the following tool to drag the points of the spline in any direction using mouse:

```
import numpy as np
from  scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.artist import Artist
from matplotlib.mlab import dist_point_to_segment


class PolygonInteractor(object):

"""
A polygon editor.
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html

Key-bindings

  't' toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
      you can move them, delete them

  'd' delete the vertex under point

  'i' insert a vertex at point.  You must be within epsilon of the
      line connecting two existing vertices

"""

showverts = True
epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

def __init__(self, ax, poly, visible=False):
    if poly.figure is None:
        raise RuntimeError('You must first add the polygon to a figure '
                           'or canvas before defining the interactor')
    self.ax = ax
    canvas = poly.figure.canvas
    self.poly = poly
    self.poly.set_visible(visible)

    x, y = zip(*self.poly.xy)
    self.line = Line2D(x, y, ls="",
                       marker='o', markerfacecolor='r',
                       animated=True)
    self.ax.add_line(self.line)

    self.cid = self.poly.add_callback(self.poly_changed)
    self._ind = None  # the active vert

    canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.draw_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)
    self.canvas = canvas

    x,y = self.interpolate()
    self.line2 = Line2D(x, y, animated=True)
    self.ax.add_line(self.line2)

def interpolate(self):
    x, y = self.poly.xy[:].T
    i = np.arange(len(x))

    interp_i = np.linspace(0, i.max(), 100 * i.max())

    xi = interp1d(i, x, kind='cubic')(interp_i)  
    yi = interp1d(i, y, kind='cubic')(interp_i)

    return xi,yi

def draw_callback(self, event):
    self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.line2)
    # do not need to blit here, this will fire before the screen is
    # updated

def poly_changed(self, poly):
    'this method is called whenever the polygon object is called'
    # only copy the artist props to the line (except visibility)
    vis = self.line.get_visible()
    Artist.update_from(self.line, poly)
    self.line.set_visible(vis)  # don't use the poly visibility state


def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
    'get the index of the vertex under point if within epsilon tolerance'

    # display coords
    xy = np.asarray(self.poly.xy)
    xyt = self.poly.get_transform().transform(xy)
    xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
    d = np.hypot(xt - event.x, yt - event.y)
    indseq, = np.nonzero(d == d.min())
    ind = indseq[0]

    if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
        ind = None

    return ind

def button_press_callback(self, event):
    'whenever a mouse button is pressed'
    if not self.showverts:
        return
    if event.inaxes is None:
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

def button_release_callback(self, event):
    'whenever a mouse button is released'
    if not self.showverts:
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    self._ind = None

def key_press_callback(self, event):
    'whenever a key is pressed'
    if not event.inaxes:
        return
    if event.key == 't':
        self.showverts = not self.showverts
        self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
        if not self.showverts:
            self._ind = None
    elif event.key == 'd':
        ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
        if ind is not None:
            self.poly.xy = np.delete(self.poly.xy,
                                     ind, axis=0)
            self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
    elif event.key == 'i':
        xys = self.poly.get_transform().transform(self.poly.xy)
        p = event.x, event.y  # display coords
        for i in range(len(xys) - 1):
            s0 = xys[i]
            s1 = xys[i + 1]
            d = dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1)
            if d <= self.epsilon:
                self.poly.xy = np.insert(
                    self.poly.xy, i+1,
                    [event.xdata, event.ydata],
                    axis=0)
                self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
                break
    if self.line.stale:
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
    'on mouse movement'
    if not self.showverts:
        return
    if self._ind is None:
        return
    if event.inaxes is None:
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

    self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x, y
    if self._ind == 0:
        self.poly.xy[-1] = x, y
    elif self._ind == len(self.poly.xy) - 1:
        self.poly.xy[0] = x, y
    self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))

    x,y = self.interpolate()
    self.line2.set_data(x,y)

    self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.line2)
    self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

#theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
#r = 1.5

#xs = r*np.cos(theta)
#ys = r*np.sin(theta)
xs = (921, 951, 993, 1035, 1065, 1045, 993, 945)
ys = (1181, 1230, 1243, 1230, 1181, 1130, 1130, 1130)

poly = Polygon(list(zip(xs, ys)), animated=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(poly)
p = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly, visible=False)

ax.set_title('Click and drag a point to move it')

ax.set_xlim((800, 1300))
ax.set_ylim((1000, 1300))

plt.show()
```

If the spline is as follows:
[image]

I wish to add additional constraints:

1) The movement of points C and G should be limited to only the Y axis, or the vertical direction, ie, the user should only be able to drag the points up or down, and not left or right

2) The movement of points A and E should be limited to only the X axis, or the horizontal direction, ie, the user should only be able to drag the points left and right, and not up or down

Can someone please suggest how to add these constraints to the given points?

EDIT--

When I drag point A left/right by some amount 'd0', then point E needs to be dragged right/left respectively by 'd0'. I tried to constrain the movement of both these points along the horizontal direction only by repeatedly setting the changed y coordinate back to it's original value whenever points are dragged. However it is not being reflected in the code.

The amount of movement 'd0' is calculated with respect to a reference center point having coordinates (993,1181)

I tried to do it as follows, by editing the motion_notify_callback() function:

```
    def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
    'on mouse movement'
    if not self.showverts:
        return
    if self._ind is None:
        return
    if event.inaxes is None:
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

    self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x, y
    if self._ind == 0:
        self.poly.xy[-1] = x, y
    elif self._ind == len(self.poly.xy) - 1:
        self.poly.xy[0] = x, y
    self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))

    xpts,ypts,x,y = self.interpolate()
    #Note that in xpts and ypts, we are getting the new coordinates of
    #the points after dragging

    if(xpts[0]<xs[0]): 
        #when point A is being dragged outwards(towards left)
            d0=abs(993-xpts[0])
            #movement amount

            ypts[0]=ys[0] #setting the y value of dragged point back to
            #original value to constrain the movement along horizontal
            #direction only. This is however not being reflected
            xpts[4] = 993+d0 #moving point E by same amount to the right
            ypts[4]=ys[4] #Trying to stop E from moving in Y direction
            d0=0

    elif(xpts[0]>xs[0]):
             #when point A is moved inwards/towards right

            d0=abs(993-xpts[0])
            ypts[0]=ys[0]
            xnew=993+d0
            xpts[4] = xnew #moving E inwards/towards left by same amount
            ypts[4]=ys[4]
            d0=0

     self.line2.set_data(x,y)
     self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
     self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
     self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
     self.ax.draw_artist(self.line2)
     self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)
     return d0
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this question before already? Any reason to think that asking it again in the same form would suddenly allow it to be answered?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I reframed that question to make it more understandable. That question was taken down

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I couldn't figure the constraints part out because I am not familiar with the matplotlib functions. Thanks for your help before. If you have any suggestions regarding this kindly advise

Comment: Fair enough. To be honest, I don't see the problem here. It might not be related to matplotlib at all? For a simple vertical or horizontal contraint you would just leave the respective coordinate untouched, e.g. if point (4,2) gets dragged to (6,3) you would just set it's x coordinate back to 4, to become (4,3).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes I tried to do that. It works in the code but doesn't reflect in the figure

Comment: I cannot see where in the code you do that. That might also be because the code is much to complex for the actual problem you want to ask about here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have included that in the edit. It can be done in the motion_notify_callback() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by restraining the coordinates of these points in the function interpolate() as follows:

```
 def interpolate(self):

    x, y = self.poly.xy[:].T

    y[0]=1181
    y[4]=1181
    x[2]=993
    x[6]=993
    #print(x,y)
    P=np.array([(x[0],y[0]),
                (x[1], y[1]),
                (x[2], y[2]),
                (x[3], y[3]),
                (x[4],y[4]),
                (x[5],y[5]),
                (x[6],y[6]),
                (x[7],y[7]),
                (x[0], y[0]),
                ])
    #print(P)

    tck, u = splprep(P.T, u=None, s=0.0, per=1)
    u_new = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), 1000)
    xi, yi = splev(u_new, tck, der=0)
    #print(xi,yi)
    #plt.plot(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], 'ro')
    #plt.plot(x_new, y_new, 'b--')
    #plt.show()

    L=0
    for j in range(0,len(xi)-1):
        L=L+np.sqrt((xi[j+1]-xi[j])**2 + (yi[j+1]-yi[j])**2)
    #print(L," pixels")
    scaled = L * 1.439464535124507
    print(scaled, " mm")
    cm = scaled / 10
    print(cm, " cm")
    inches = scaled * 0.0394
    print(inches, "inch")
    print("\n")

    return x,y,xi,yi
```

The point may be moved on the screen if you drag it but the spline would always be fit along the same coordinates as defined